# Storing a value from ios-xe router command output in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, cisco-ios

After making a connection to a cisco device using python, and executing a command I get a output as shown below,
Basically I want to get only one value, that the value for `Services` which is shown as `1` below and store it in a variable.

```
#show ethernet cfm domain brief
Domain Name                              Index Level Services Archive(min)
EVC                                          2     4        1     100
```

I'm not sure how to parse this, I tried converting to a list, but the list became very huge something like this and I dont know if the same will work on another cisco ios-xe device.

```
['Domain', 'Name', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Index', 'Level', 'Services', 'Archive(min)\r\nEVC', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '2', '', '', '', '', '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '100']
```

Is there any other reliable way to get the value of `services` which is `1` ?

Comment: textfsm package can help you

Answer (score 0):

Example how to use TextFSM to parse output of "show ethernet cfm domain brief"

Create **template.textfsm** template file with the following context

```
Value DOMAIN_NAME (\S+)
Value INDEX (\S+)
Value LEVEL (\S+)
Value SERVICES (\S+)
Value ARCHIVE (\S+)

Start
  ^Domain Name\s+Index\s+Level\s+Services\s+Archive\(min\)
  ^${DOMAIN_NAME}\s+${INDEX}\s+${LEVEL}\s+${SERVICES}\s+${ARCHIVE} -> Record
```

and use this template to parse your output

```py
import textfsm

# show ethernet cfm domain brief
output = """
Domain Name                              Index Level Services Archive(min)
EVC                                          2     4        1     100
"""

with open("template.textfsm", "r") as f:
    template = textfsm.TextFSM(f)
    items = [dict(zip(template.header, row)) for row in template.ParseText(output)]
    print(items)  # [{'DOMAIN_NAME': 'EVC', 'INDEX': '2', 'LEVEL': '4', 'SERVICES': '1', ...

    for item in items:
        print(item["SERVICES"])  # 1
```